# Unable to read updated data from csv/excel file in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am running 2 test cases in TestNG. One is writing data in to Excel file and another one is reading that written data from Excel file. When I try to read data from csv/excel file it reads the previous data not the newly added data.

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. Can we see your `code` to see the issue ?

Comment: not sure which is worse, when someone copy pastes an error message from IDE or this. like @Akzy said, provide your code and an actual error.